# Unable to locate credentials for Federated user in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, federated-identity

I run a command:

```
aws s3 ls
```

and system says:

> Unable to locate credentials

In order to find "AWS Access Key ID" and "AWS Secret Access Key", I login in to AWS console.

Top right corner shows: `AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_123abc456abc/myusername@myemployer.com`

In this case, how do I configure my credentials?

[image]

Comment: See: [Token provider configuration with automatic authentication refresh for AWS IAM Identity Center (successor to AWS Single Sign-On) - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use saml2aws:

```
saml2aws --idp-account="default" --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD
```

For executing commands, you can use:

```
saml2aws --idp-account="default" --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD exec command
```

Or aws cli itself

```
aws configure sso
```